# Python Selenium to automate Twitter likes

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

I'm trying to automate the process of liking all the tweets in one page with Selenium for Python but I can't understand how to perform the click action on the specific like button.

This is the html for the like button:

```
<button class="ProfileTweet-actionButton js-actionButton js-actionFavorite" type="button" aria-describedby="profile-tweet-action-favorite-count-aria-1056501001434349568">
    <div class="IconContainer js-tooltip" data-original-title="Like">
      <span role="presentation" class="Icon Icon--heart Icon--medium"></span>
      <div class="HeartAnimation"></div>
      <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Like</span>
    </div>
      <span class="ProfileTweet-actionCount">
    <span class="ProfileTweet-actionCountForPresentation" aria-hidden="true">1</span>
  </span>

  </button>
```

I'm trying this but the action does not take place:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-actionFavorite").click()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Automated liking is against Twitter's Automation Rules https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but you cannot use compound names with find_element_by_class_name.

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class="ProfileTweet-actionButton js-actionButton js-actionFavorite"]').click()
```

Comment: thank you; tried it but it does not click on the like button specifically

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're already with the new twitter layout. In my case, everything has already changed. I was able to do the like in the first item of the profile only.

```
# var for css selection item

like_it = "section.css-1dbjc4n > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > 
div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
> article:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) >
div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)"

# like 1st tweet timeline user.
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(like_it).click()
```

ps: To give like in several profile tweets, I still have not figured out how to do it.